# Supporting shorter than recommended authentication tags in Go AES-GCM AEAD

Tags: go, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

We have an existing AES-GCM AEAD encryption scheme in place, using 4 bytes as tag length. The tag length is suitable for the security needs of our application - the tag is not critical.

We are going to implement the scheme in a Go application, and its standard library's limit of only allowing AES-GCM tags of 12 bytes length and longer is causing some pain. We would need to support messages between the existing implementations and the new Go application, so extending the tag in the scheme is not feasible.

The public interface on `crypto.cipher.NewGCMWithTagSize` refuses the tag size, as demonstrated in the programme below. I also tried using `crypto.aes.aesCipherGCM.NewGCM`, available on 64-bit platforms through interface casting, but it panics instead of throwing errors.

Is there a way to achieve the shorter tags, using the standard or a 3rd party library? Alternatively, is there a way to decrypt the payload, while ignoring tags?

```
package main 

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

const (
    nonceSize = 12
    tagSize   = 4
)

func Decrypt(key []byte, extra string, encrypted string) error {
    cipherBytes, err := base64.URLEncoding.WithPadding(base64.NoPadding).DecodeString(encrypted)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    nonce := cipherBytes[:nonceSize]
    ciphertext := cipherBytes[nonceSize:]

    aes, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCMWithTagSize(aes, tagSize)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    plain, err := aesgcm.Open(nil, nonce, ciphertext, []byte(extra))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(plain)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    key, _ := hex.DecodeString("12345678123456781234567812345678")
    err := Decrypt(key, "test", "NnzdIfRlBvimLC9AQ7U07I4lj3aEogAZE4eDve2W1SrJwKsCnQ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %s\n", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Instead of the payload, the output is `error: cipher: incorrect tag size given to GCM`.

Comment: https://github.com/CrackedPoly/AES-go

Comment: If you can't find another solution/library, you can simply remove the constraints (in `newGCMWithNonceAndTagSize()` and `Open()`), see [here](https://go.dev/play/p/M4PuoU6iSIJ). Note that for a 4 bytes tag the constraints from [NIST SP800-38D, Appendix C](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf) have to be considered.